# How to kill the SDL thread which is blocked in I/O in android

Tags: sdl, sdl-2

1) Android does not support Thread cancellation, hence i can not cancel the thread which is blocked.

Are there any quirk that i need to be aware of?..  The finest goal is to throw a thread out of the system gracefully in SDL.

Any light that can be shown on it ?

As Additional Information:

From Migration Notes of SDL 2

https://wiki.libsdl.org/MigrationGuide#Threads

"
SDL_KillThread() is gone. It was never safe or reliable. The best replacement is to set a flag that tells a thread it should quit. That thread should check the flag with some frequency, and then the "killing" thread calls SDL_WaitThread() to clean up.
"

Comment: Thread is blocked how?

Comment: For example thread that communicates with UDP protocol. In case of some network failure, there could be a delayed timeout with UDP. that's was i meant thread is blocked.

Comment: Killing the thread is not ok. Change your timeout function or use a different thread manager or spawn that in a different thread.